How to retrieve original JS native constructor if they are changed? Say Map
I am working on a browser extension where I am using a library which need to use Native js Map. However it's definition has been changed by the host application. Additionally library which I am using need Native Map at the time of loading. Is there a way I can retrieve original Map definition?
I tried below 2 approaches.

constructing new iframe and access it's Map definition. Problem was that library uses Map on load and I can't pass Map definition to it.

Used web worker. Chrome MV3 is not allowing to create a new Worker from the content script.



Do you run the code in the MAIN world and if so why? In case it's really necessary, you can run your script at document_start and save the original constructor.
